# How to use OBIEE over SAP BW?

Tags: obiee, sap-bw

I have a requirement where I need to use OBIEE for reporting using SAP BW CUBES/MULTIPROVIDERS.

How can we do it?

Is the BW cube itself is implemented in the OBIEE or the reports those are developed on the BW CUBES can imported into the OBIEE.

Please suggest something or if any good source you can provide.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

There could be issues in importing SAP BW cubes. 
Once we had to install separate, "tailored for SAP BW"; OBIEE installation provided by Oracle Support.
Better if you could resolve such technical issues before investing further.